# Apply array to array in Groovy

Tags: list, groovy

I just found that code:

```
[1,2] [4, 4]
```

is completely valid in Groovy but can't find what does such expression evaluates to, for me it returns null in all possible cases:

```
groovy:000> [1, 2] []
===> []
groovy:000> [1, 2] [4] 
===> null
groovy:000> [1, 2] [4,5]
===> [null, null]
```

So basically the question is what does the expression:

```
a = list1 list2
```

mean in Groovy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In groovy, the `[]` operator is just a shorthand for `getAt()`, so in this case it's calling the method [`List.getAt(Collection)`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#getAt%28java.util.Collection%29).

The behavior is to return a list containing all the elements whose index is listed in the collection.  So for `[1,2][4,5]`, it's returning a list with elements 4 and 5, which both happen to be out of range, so null.

Here are some examples that illustrate it a little better:

```
assert ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'][1, 3] == ['b', 'd']
assert [0, 1, 2, 3, 4][4..0] == [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: @MichaelRutherfurd Well, it usually won't make sense to use the subscript with a literal I think. `def firstAndThird = [4,3,2,1][0,2]` doesn't make too much sense, but `def firstAndThird = someList[0,2]` does a bit more :)

Comment: @MichaelRutherfurd BTW, I think you are right about this syntax being confusing, as it clashes with the parentheses-less method call syntax. `foo.bar 1` means `foo.bar(1)`, but `foo.bar [1]` does _not_ mean `foo.bar([1])`. And `foo.bar 1, 2` is legal syntax, but `foo.bar [1], 2` yields a syntax error :). I think what is confusing is the parentheses-less syntax; it has many corner-cases that makes its usage ugly.

Comment: Scala has paren-less syntax so Groovy needs it too! Just keeping up with the Joneses.